# Android Apps run well on android studio but not compatible in store

Tags: android, google-play, compatibility

I've been developing with a device in android studio, and run well, no issue at all.
But after I released it in store, some devices including mine could not find it because it was incompatible.

Is there anyway to find out why my device isn't compatible in store?

Answer (score 0):

You must be setting your minSdkVersion higher than your device sdk version in build.gradle or setting supports-screens to the limited device in your manifest.

Apart from that if you are using some hardware permission which is not necessary then set required false in manifest.

e.g

```
<uses-feature
    android:name="android.hardware.camera"
    android:required="false" />
```

Comment: minSdkVersion 17, targetSdkVersion 26

Comment: What's your device sdk version and are you using any `supports-screens` in you manifest?

Comment: my device sdk is 17 and no support-screens in manifest. If there is something wrong, i wont be able to run it

Comment: Check any hardware requirements.

Comment: i mean I can use my device in android studio, but when i upload it in store, it says not compatible

Comment: That happens when you some hardware permission which is unavailable in your device.

Comment: that's my question. How to find out why is my device incompatible?

Comment: Please note that I use my device when developing and there are no issue at all

Comment: It will never throw exception in development.

Answer (score 0):

you beat me by seconds to the answer except mine was wrong. :)

Well not exactly- what I was going to say is that Android Studio has great documentation and I remember reading about that when I first downloaded it.

If you want to run on older devices the best way to be sure is to download a VM that is the lowest possible supported version and test on that before dist.

All the best.

Comment: I can use my device in android studio, but when i upload it in store, it says not compatible